# Can QTP be used without actual UI to test services?

Tags: automated-tests, soa, qtp

I know QTP is used for GUI testing. I am going to test SOA architecture and would need to call services and checks results but before the UI is implemented.
I have heard QTP is capable of doing it (sending requests etc.) but was not able to verify if it is really possible with zero UI.
I guess if it is possible, all will be script-based.

Answer (score 1):

Historically you could use QTP's [WebService addin](http://automatictester.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/qtp-web-services-add-in-tutorial/) in order to test GUI-less services.

With the current release of Unified Functional Testing (UFT) there are two different types of tests. GUI tests (previously known as QTP tests) and API tests (previously known as Service Tests).

So no matter which version of QTP you choose to use you will be able to perform non-GUI based tests.